# A property that is read-only outside of the class, but read-write for class members

Tags: typescript

I'd like to have a property in my class that is readable, but not directly modifiable by code external to the class. Basically, equivalent of returning a const reference to member from a method in C++.

Writing something along those lines:

```
class test {
    private readonly x_ = new Uint8Array([0, 1, 2]);
    public x() { return this.x_;}
}
```

does not work, because code like the following still compiles:

```
let a = new test();
a.x()[0] = 1;
```

What's the correct way of achieving this?

Comment: Hey could you update the question title? it's kinda misleading because it appears to focus on simple class properties, while what you actually ask is how to make an array property items unmodifiable from outside the class, so it's more like "shading the actual property type".

Answer (score 18):

For future readers, We can use `getter` to allow reading property outside class, but restrict edit.

```
class Test {
    private x_ = new Uint8Array([0, 1, 2]);

    get x() {
        return this.x_;
    }
}
```

```
let test = new Test();
console.log(test.x) //Can read
test.x = 1; //Error: Cannot assign to 'x' because it is a read-only property.
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like that:

```
interface ReadonlyTypedArray<T> {
    readonly [index: number]: T
}

class test {
    private _x = new Uint8Array([0, 1, 2]);
    public get x(): ReadonlyTypedArray<number> {
        return this._x;
    }
}

let a = new test();
a.x[0] = 1; // Error: Left-hand side of assignment expression cannot be a constant or a read-only property.
a.x = new Uint8Array([0, 1, 2]); // Error: Left-hand side of assignment expression cannot be a constant or a read-only property.
```

Comment: This almost works, but the problem is that it loses type information... I.e., I can't pass `a.x` to `uniformMatrix4fv`, because the typescript compiler sees it  as `ReadonlyTypedArray<number>` instead of `Float32Array`

Comment: @nicebyte But a typed array `Uint8Array` can be mutated. If a function needs a parameter of type `Float32Array`, then it can mutate it.

Answer (score 0):

A second private property `xValue` can be declared. It would contain the value and be editable from inside. The public property `x` would be only a getter (preferably `getX` method to prevent confusion).